# Unable to connect my android app to localhost server

Tags: php, android, mysql

*Hi I am developing an android application, the database is exact replica of the database used in localhost, that is to say the number of fields used in android db and php db are the same. Any entry I make in the php db should be synced to the android db. I am writing the code below for both php side and android side, please tell me why is not able to connect.*

receive_reques.php

```
<?php
// receive_request.php

// get the last entry from the database table
$query = "select last(Bank_Name,Account,Type,Date,Amount,Cheque_no,Cheque_party,Cheque_details) from `transaction`";

$query_run = mysql_query($query);
$response = "";
$response = mysql_fetch_row($query_run);

echo implode(":",$response);

?>
```

Android sync code:

```
public void postData()
{

    HttpClient httpclient  = new DefaultHttpClient();


    //  calls the local host and then the receive_request file for data values

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("ip_of_localhost\final_year\receive_request.php");

    try{
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // convert the response received to String format
        String array[] = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).split(":");
        // now store them in dbms and display them in the layout

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // process execption
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // process execption
    }


}
```

**I am getting an error which says- Connection to`"http://ip_of_localhost/final_year_receive_request.php"` refused**

Comment: Please avoid tabs in your code, better is to use 4 spaces for indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `10.0.2.2` instead of `127.0.0.1`

> Also note that the address 127.0.0.1 on your development machine
>   corresponds to the emulator's own loopback interface. If you want to
>   access services running on your development machine's loopback
>   interface (a.k.a. 127.0.0.1 on your machine), you should use the
>   special address 10.0.2.2 instead.

[`Source`](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: More info > http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: @Shankar I am creating an adhoc network of the server and the app. I got a ip address of the server and using that address as "ip_of_localhost" I called the receive_request.php file, but its still not working.

Comment: @Svetlio, Exactly, I was about to paste that link ;)

Comment: Have you tried adding `http://` infront of it ? Why pass IP btw ? Doesn't that IP have a hostname ?

Comment: @Shankar See the problem is I don't know how the application would automatically detect the server's ip, so I am passing it to the function which calls the receicve_request.php page, but on pressing sync button I get the same error that connection to this ip address REFUSED, why do you think is it getting refused?, please help me out